# Google+ API ItemScope getRatingValue returns null string

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

In my android app using the Google+ API, I am able to write moments of type "ReviewActivity" with the following code :

```
ItemScope rating = new ItemScope.Builder()
            .setType("http://schema.org/Rating")
            .setRatingValue(Float.toString(oeuvre.getRating()))
            .setBestRating("5").setWorstRating("0").build();
ItemScope result = new ItemScope.Builder()
            .setType("http://schema.org/Review").setName(titre)
            .setUrl(urlfreebase)
            .setDescription(oeuvre.getNomPeintre()).setReviewRating(rating)
            .build();
ItemScope target = new ItemScope.Builder().setUrl(urlfreebase).build();
Moment moment = new Moment.Builder()
            .setType("http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity")
            .setTarget(target).setResult(result).build();
if (monPlusClient.isConnected()) {
    monPlusClient.writeMoment(moment);
}
```

Its works, I can read them in my Google+ profile with my Desktop.

When I load moments, at the beginning of my app, I am also able to read my moments, but I am unable to get the rating value that was chose by the user.

In my listener :

```
public void onMomentsLoaded(ConnectionResult status,
        MomentBuffer momentBuffer, String nextPageToken, String updated) {
...
}
```

I receive this target :

```
{"description":"Pablo Picasso","url":"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/+\/web\/snippet\/examples\/review","id":"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/+\/web\/snippet\/examples\/review","reviewRating":{"ratingValue":"4.0","worstRating":"0","bestRating":"5"},"name":"Le Pigeon aux petits pois"}
```

As you can see the rating is correctly set :

```
"reviewRating":{"ratingValue":"4.0","worstRating":"0","bestRating":"5"}
```

but when I try to read it through the API with :

```
ItemScope res = m.getResult();
String titre = res.getName();
String desc = res.getDescription();
String streval = res.getRatingValue();
```

the String streval is always null

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using JSON strings :

```
ItemScope res = m.getResult();
String titre = res.getName();
String desc = res.getDescription();
try {
    JSONObject jres = new JSONObject(res.toString());
    JSONObject jeval = jres.getJSONObject("reviewRating");
    String streval = jeval.getString("ratingValue");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```